# Embedded fonts do not worked correctly for Flash

Tags: flash, flash-cs6

i embeded font our fla file. Then i use it our TLF text title and other TLF texts. run swf and i see some text use our font but some text System Font (_sans). Are there somebody Why do it this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6CmA.png

Answer (score 0):

Are the text fields placed on the stage by you or are they dynamically generated by actionscript?

If they're manually placed on the stage by you, select each text that isn't displaying correctly and double check the font selected in the Family dropdown on the Properties tab.

All embedded fonts will appear toward the very top of the Family dropdown list with an asterisk beside the name given when embedded.

If they're generated dynamically, please post some related code for us to look at.